Using Symfony Process to execute composer install but verbose output is returning as error output
I'm working on a utility to manage projects and I can't get the process output correct for composer install using the Symfony Process.
Does anyone know why the composer install output is reported as 'error' output even though it runs successfully? Is there a better way to handle this output?
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['composer', 'install', '--verbose', '--prefer-dist', '--no-progress', '--no-interaction', '--no-dev', '--optimize-autoloader']);

$process->run(); // returns 0
$process->isSuccessful(); // returns true
$process->getErrorOutput(); // returns the Installing output?? Why is this considered error output

// getErrorOutput() ....
Installing dependencies from lock file\n
  Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.\n
  Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds\n
  Package operations: 66 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals\n
  Installs: doctrine/inflector:2.0.6, doctrine/lexer:1.2.3, symfony/polyfill-ctype:v1.27.0, webmozart/assert:1.11.0, dragonmantank/cron-expression:v3.3.2, voku/portable-ascii:1.6.1, symfony/polyfill-php80:v1.27.0, symfony/polyfill-mbstring:v1.27.0, phpoption/phpoption:1.9.0, graham-campbell/result-type:v1.1.0, vlucas/phpdotenv:v5.5.0, symfony/css-selector:v5.4.11, tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles:2.2.5, symfony/var-dumper:v5.4.14, symfony/deprecation-contracts:v2.5.2, symfony/routing:v5.4.15, symfony/process:v5.4.11, symfony/polyfill-php72:v1.27.0, symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer:v1.27.0, symfony/polyfill-intl-idn:v1.27.0, symfony/mime:v5.4.14, symfony/polyfill-php73:v1.27.0, symfony/http-foundation:v5.4.15, psr/event-dispatcher:1.0.0, symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts:v2.5.2, symfony/event-dispatcher:v5.4.9, psr/log:1.1.4, symfony/error-handler:v5.4.15, symfony/http-kernel:v5.4.15, symfony/finder:v5.4.11, symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme:v1.27.0, symfony/string:v5.4.15, psr/container:1.1.1, symfony/service-contracts:v2.5.2, symfony/console:v5.4.15, symfony/polyfill-iconv:v1.27.0, egulias/email-validator:2.1.25, swiftmailer/swiftmailer:v6.3.0, symfony/polyfill-php81:v1.27.0, ramsey/collection:1.2.2, brick/math:0.9.3, ramsey/uuid:4.2.3, psr/simple-cache:1.0.1, opis/closure:3.6.3, symfony/translation-contracts:v2.5.2, symfony/translation:v5.4.14, nesbot/carbon:2.63.0, monolog/monolog:2.8.0, league/mime-type-detection:1.11.0, league/flysystem:1.1.10, league/commonmark:1.6.7, laravel/serializable-closure:v1.2.2, laravel/framework:v8.83.26, asm89/stack-cors:v2.1.1, fruitcake/laravel-cors:v2.2.0, psr/http-message:1.0.1, psr/http-client:1.0.1, ralouphie/getallheaders:3.0.3, psr/http-factory:1.0.1, guzzlehttp/psr7:2.4.3, guzzlehttp/promises:1.5.2, guzzlehttp/guzzle:7.5.0, laravel/sanctum:v2.15.1, nikic/php-parser:v4.15.2, psy/psysh:v0.11.9, laravel/tinker:v2.7.2\n
    - Downloading doctrine/inflector (2.0.6)\n
    - Downloading doctrine/lexer (1.2.3)\n
    - Downloading symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0)\n
    - Downloading dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.2)\n
...


stdErr is not just for errors, it is for everything that is not the direct output of the process, including diagnostic and informational messages. There’s a thread on it, too.

Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense and I appreciate the context provided by the thread.

to determine if a composer command ran successfully or not, use the exit status code. non-zero means there was an error.
